# Python beautiful soup find content in class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I got a html like this:

```
<div class="row" data-keywordid="53707903">
     <div class="kw-table-cell kw-keyword-name-cell">
     </div>
</div>
```

In normal case i can take content inner of class "row" by using:
`soup.find("div",{"class": "row"})`
but what i want is get the `data-keywordid` and value of that `53707903`. I have no idea for it. Have anyway to get it? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = ''''
    <div class="row" data-keywordid="53707903">
     <div class="kw-table-cell kw-keyword-name-cell">
     </div>
    </div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

a = soup.find('div')

a.attrs['data-keywordid']
```